# What is grid layout using CSS?

Tags: css

Difference between grid and liquid layouts? Looking for explanation of a grid layout.thanks

Comment: Be aware that most grid layouts are fixed-width, which *really* irritates a subset of your users. It's popular because it offers the illusion of a bit more control (and who knows, perhaps the reality of a *bit* more control as well). A number of us are not fans of being told how wide to make our browser windows (are you listening, SO?), being of the absurd belief that we (the end user) should control that.

Answer (score 2):

- Grid layouts are built more towards a specific width no matter how wide a user's browser window is.
- Liquid layouts expand/contract based on the width of the user's browser window.

Comment: Examples of frameworks using grid layouts:
 - http://960.gs
 - http://blueprintcss.org
 - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids

Answer (score 0):

Grid layouts are frameworks that work by using columns and rows of fixed size.  You have to decide on the width you want the page to be and use a relatively complex range of classes to create basically a table layout.  Check out one of the most popular ones:

http://960.gs/

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of pointers to good grid layout systems in other answers, I like [Yahoo's UI Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) a lot.  It can do fixed-width layouts and 100% (fluid) layouts, and there's a nice tool that allows you to play with different layouts.

Fixed-width layouts have the advantage of being more predictable than fluid layouts in many cases.